# LESS code to CSS with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, less

Is there a way to convert LESS code to CSS with Javascript?
Having the LESS code in a javascript variable, I want to compile it, and to get the CSS code into another javascript variable.

**EDIT!**

I want to convert a LESS code snippet to CSS with JS.
User writes LESS code in a textarea and my code has to convert it to CSS real time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are using less.js you can do the following:

```
var parser = new(less.Parser);

parser.parse(myLessCode, function (err, tree) {
    if (err) { return console.error(err) }
    css = tree.toCSS();
    console.log(css);
});
```

Checked it in jsfiddle and it works: http://jsfiddle.net/3AHTW/